# Java While Loop Not Ending

Tags: java, while-loop

I am very new to java and decided to start a new project recently to help myself learn. My project is an impossible quiz. I started making my first question in the quiz and ran into a problem. I have a while loop that is supposed to exit the question if the player runs out of lives however it is not working. The while loop looks like:

```
    //
    //LEVEL ONE
    //
    while (lives != 0 || !correct == true) {

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.err.print("Level: ");
        System.out.print(currentlevel);
        System.out.println(" ");

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        System.err.print("Lives: ");
        System.out.println(lives);

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        System.err.print("Skips: ");
        System.out.println(skips);

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Question: If there are 6 apples in a tree and you take 4, how many do you have?");

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        System.out.println("A: 3");
        System.out.println("B: 4");
        System.out.println("C: 2");
        System.out.println("D: 6");

        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {

            Scanner questionone = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = questionone.nextLine();

            switch (choice) {
                case "a":
                    System.out.println("WRONG! Try again.");
                    lives = lives - 1;
                    break;
                case "b":
                    System.out.println("CORRECT! You have the 4 you took obviously.");
                    correct = true;
                    break;
                case "c":
                    System.out.println("WRONG! Try again.");
                    lives = lives - 1;
                    break;
                case "d":
                    System.out.println("WRONG! Try again.");
                    lives = lives - 1;
                    System.out.println(lives);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please type an answer.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("test");

    //
    //LEVEL TWO
    //
```

PS. Yes I have spent a lot of time trying to figure it out on my own and also seeing if anyone else has had the same problem.

Comment: If you're not going to design a solution that requires objects and uses an object-oriented approach ... then just write your program in a simple procedural language like Basic.

Comment: Can you create a simplified version of your program that illustrates the problem without drowning it out with all the unrelated code?

Comment: You're making like...three instances of `Scanner` when you only need one.

Comment: Also, this is a lot of code all in `main()`. As scottb suggests, you should learn about Object Oriented Programming techniques. At the very least, you should break this up into smaller methods, each of which carries out a very specific task.

Comment: To all the folks that are asking the OP to design this in a more OO fashion:  I ***really*** doubt that anyone here starting out with Java had the first idea of making their code more modular.  They're just starting out; at least cut them *that* much slack.

Comment: I have edited my post so there is less unnecessary code. Also thank you for all your suggestions so far. I will consider them but please try to focus on the question and not the fact that YES as I stated before, I am new to java.

Comment: Wait a moment @KobiF; you actually had copy-and-paste code that could be *run* in an IDE.  Don't lose *that*.

Comment: As far as the `while(lives != 0 || !correct == true)` test goes, you're doing quite a bit of logic reversal. From first-hand experience, reversing logic multiple times gets very confusing very fast.. Recommend something a bit more straightforward, like `while(lives > 0 || correct == false) { ... }`.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you Loi Ly for finding the issue. Also thank you everyone else for giving me helpful tips on java in general. I will definitely consider all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
while (lives != 0 || !correct == true) {
```

You stop your while when your correct = true OR your lives = 0

It will also mean: You continue your while when your correct = false AND your lives != 0.

So change your condition to

```
while (lives != 0 && !correct == true) {
```

And more, the condition of the while:

```
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
```

You see, your while loop ( the inside one ) will ONLY stop when you input "b" from your keyboard. So that when you press a ( you lost 1 live ), and a a a a ..etc, your lives will be negative number.

So change to:

```
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("b") && lives != 0) {
```

to check whether you have live or not.

Good luck!

Comment: @Jhonny007 Of course, but not neccessary, it just clearer, not solve the problem. So that I keep it for him. By the way, comparing bool type to bool type is a bad practice ^^

Answer (score 1):

Change || for &&...

`while (lives != 0 || !correct == true)`

`while (lives != 0 && !correct == true)`

Comment: Would you ***pretty please*** change `!correct == true` to just `!correct`??

Comment: The explanation: **two orred negations** almost always are wrong.

Comment: That would be pleasant for my eyes as well haha
But I'm just showing the error...

Answer (score -1):

```
!correct == true
```

This is a strange syntax - !correct would mean that correct evaluates to false, however you are saying if if it is false then it is true - basically just get rid of ==true. Also change || to &&. Good luck!